# fixing leaflet legend to make it show lines rather than boxes

Tags: r, leaflet

I am making a map using leaflet showing blocks from 2000, and tracts from 2000 and 2010. Right now, I can't get the legend to work correctly: it shows colored boxes instead of colored lines:

```
az_2000 <- tracts(state = "Arizona", year = 2000) %>% 
  select(c(CTIDFP00)) %>% rename("geoid" = "CTIDFP00")
az_2000 <- st_transform(az_2000, 4326)

az_bg2000 <- blocks(state = "Arizona", year = 2000) %>% 
  select(c(BLKIDFP00)) %>% rename("geoid" = "BLKIDFP00")
az_bg2000 <- st_transform(az_bg2000)

az_2010 <- tracts(state = "Arizona", year = 2010) %>% 
  select(c(GEOID10)) %>% rename("geoid" = "GEOID10")
az_2010 <- st_transform(az_2010, 4326)
    

# Create a map with the three layers
map <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = az_bg2000,
              fill = FALSE,
              color = "#000000",
              dashArray = "2",
              weight = 0.5,
              label = "Blocks 2000") %>%
  addPolygons(data = az_2000, 
              fill = FALSE, 
              color = "#0000FF", 
              weight = 3,
              label = "Tracts 2000") %>%
  addPolygons(data = az_2010, 
              fill = FALSE, 
              color = "#FF0000",
              dashArray = "5,5",
              weight = 3,
              label = "Tracts 2010") %>%
  addLegend(position = "bottomright", 
            colors = c("#000000", "#0000FF", "#FF0000"), 
            labels = c("Blocks 2000", "Tracts 2000", "Tracts 2010"), 
            title = "Legend")
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: what happens if you `legendLine = TRUE)` after the last line like : `...title = "Legend", legendLine =TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit of a hack, but you could use an onRender function to apply some css to the legend elements to make them look how you want.

```
# Create a map with the three layers
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addLegend(position = "bottomright", 
            colors = c("#000000", "#0000FF", "#FF0000"), 
            labels = c("Blocks 2000", "Tracts 2000", "Tracts 2010"), 
            title = "Legend") %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender("
    function(el, x) {
      let legend = document.getElementsByClassName('info legend leaflet-control')[0].getElementsByTagName('i')
      for (let i of legend){
        i.style.transform = 'scale(1, 0.2)'
      }
    }")
```

[image]